# Как в JavaScript выполнить извлечение значений во время переборки?

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно сформировать набор переменных по следующему образцу:

```
 var imageUrl = 'http://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/historical/newark_nj_1922.jpg';
 var imageBounds = [[40.712216, -74.22655], [46.773941, -79.12544]];
```

Все нужные мне данные находятся в переменной в виде массивов объектов:

`[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]`

Вот таким образом я выполняю итерацию по ним:

```
 rasters_previews_list.forEach(function(item) { 
       console.log(item.imageUrl);
       console.log(item.imageBounds);
   });
```

Координаты в массиве хранятся у меня в виде:

`POLYGON((12.562 14.603,8.416 13.653,9.156 9.205,13.294 10.094,12.562 14.603))`

Мне же нужен именно такой формат как указан выше т.е.

`[40.712216, -74.22655], [46.773941, -79.12544]`

Тоесть первая группа, вторую пропускаем и третья группа. Должно получиться:

`[12.562 14.603], [9.156 9.205]`

Т.е. в итоге обхода группы объектов я должен получать пары:

`imageUrl`
`imageBounds`

Каждую из этих пар я буду передавать в функцию:

`L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(Window.map)`

Проблема в том, что я никак не могу понять как итерацию по `item.imageBounds` написать, чтобы выбрать оттуда только первое-третье значение и преобразовать его именно к указанному виду.

Answer (score 1):

Учитвыая что полигон можно привести к массиву

```
// ES6 syntax
const result = rasters_previews_list.map((item) => { 
  const bounds = item.imageBounds.toArray().map((bound, idx) => {
    if (idx == 0 || idx == 2) {
      return bound;
    }
  }) 
  return {
    imageUrl: item.imageUrl,
    imageBounds: bounds
  }
});

 // ES5 syntax
var result = rasters_previews_list.map(function(item) { 
  var bounds = item.imageBounds.toArray().map(function(bound, idx) {
    if (idx == 0 || idx == 2) {
      return bound;
    }
  }) 
  return {
    imageUrl: item.imageUrl,
    imageBounds: bounds
  }
});
```

Учитывая что полигон это строка

```
 // ES5 syntax
var result = rasters_previews_list.map(function(item) { 
  var bounds = item.imageBounds.substring(imageBounds.lastIndexOf('(') + 1, imageBounds.indexOf(')') - 1).split(',').map(function(bound, idx) {
    if (idx == 0 || idx == 2) {
      return bound.split(' ').map(function(value) { return parseFloat(value) });
    }
  });
  return {
    imageUrl: item.imageUrl,
    imageBounds: bounds
  };
});

console.log(result); //Вывод результата
result.forEach(function(item) { L.imageOverlay(item.imageUrl, item.imageBounds).addTo(Window.map) } );
```

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что в последнем примере в последней строке мы все передаем уже в сам элемент карты?

В какой момент можно сделать вывод данных, чтобы посмотреть на то что передается глазами?

Comment: Обновил последний пример